# How do I change the DEFINER of a VIEW in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, permissions

When I run mysqldump, I get an error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1449: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'foobar') does not exist when using LOCK TABLES
```

This makes sense because `foobar` is a legacy machine that no longer exists.

How do I change the definer of all my tables to 'root'@'localhost'?

Comment: Do you have Views? Tables don't have definers I'm sure... Also see http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4129/630

Comment: @gbn +1 you were right - they were views - thx for the link, but I couldn't get it working quite right.  However, I was able to modify the views in SQLyog so I could do the dump.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What I think is that the database you are trying to dump contains procedures/methods that were defined by a user while logged in as root@'foobar'.

Now the solution is that you have to replace the definer's for that procedures/methods

then you can generate the dump without the error.

you can do this like ..

```
 UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'root@localhost' WHERE definer='root@foobar'
```

Be careful, because this will change all the definers for all databases.

Try it....!

**UPDATE on 9th Feb 2012**

As I saw the link given by @gbn which is an answer given by @Rolando that can also be the Case. [Please visit the link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/modify-definer-on-many-views)

**EDIT by @RolandoMySQLDBA 2011-12-16 11:20 EDT**

While risky, this answer is good. Just to clarify: You can specify the database in your query like this:

```
 UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'root@localhost' WHERE definer='root@foobar' AND db='whateverdbyouwant';
```

Comment: This answer works for changing the definers of procedures and functions but does not change the definer of a *View*.

Answer (score 37):

Easier to use the `--single-transaction` switch:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u username -p db > db.sql
```

Comment: Sorry, how this addresses the problem desribed in the original question?  Looks like you answered the wrong question...

Comment: The structure of the answer is wrong, because --single-transaction needs to be prior to the database name, but the answer is actually correct.  Specifying this option works around the issue by changing the locking behavior of mysqldump, so the error in the original question no longer occurs.

Answer (score 18):

The quickest solution would just be to re-create the definer so it does exist, as long as it doesn't create any conflicts with existing users.

`CREATE USER 'root'@'foobar';`

Comment: What if the user was 'root'@'%'? I simply deny such thing on a server we're responsible for.

Comment: @AttilaFulop Yes, security definitely should be a consideration, but I said this was the "quickest" solution, not the perfect one. Once the import is complete the user could be deleted to mitigate risks of having extra users.

Comment: You're right in that. I just wanted to draw attention to this particular aspect as well. My workmates would have added 'root'@'%' and leave it there as long as Chuck Norris is alive ie. forever ;)

Answer (score 7):

Export all the views of the database `<DB>`:

```
mysql -BNe "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<DB>' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'" \
    information_schema | xargs mysqldump --single-transaction --no-data <DB> >views.sql
```

or:

```
mysql -BNe "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<DB>'" \
    information_schema | xargs mysqldump --single-transaction --no-data <DB> >views.sql
```

Edit `views.sql` and recreate them:

```
cat views.sql | mysql <DB>
```

Specify `-u` and `-p` switches if necessary.