# Why mysqldump is returning with error 1143: Couldn't execute 'show table status like

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

I ran the following command to create a `mysqldump`

```
mysqldump -ubackup -psomething --single-transaction --quick somedatabase | gzip > 4_19.gz
```

I got following error after 60% (estimating checking size of the zip file) of the dump created:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show table status like 'customer\_cohort\_paid'': SELECT command denied to user ''@'%' for column 'customer_id' in table 'sales_order' (1143)
```

It says of about permission issues for a blank user `user ''@'%'`. Moreover, `grants` for `backup` user is as followed:

```
mysql> show grants for 'backup'@'%';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for backup@%                                                                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'backup'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*SOMETHING' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug report on this: [mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show table status': SELECT command denied to user](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70907). Surprisingly, it's not a bug at all. here is why:

`customer_cohort_paid might` be a view. Whatever user created the view is not listed anymore in `mysql.user`. What this does is make such a view incapable of being dumped.

You could do one of two(2) things

## SUGGESTION #1

Force the dump with `-f`

```
mysqldump -f -ubackup -psomething --single-transaction --quick somedatabase | gzip > 4_19.gz
```

If you can force the dump to make views appear in the dump file, you may want to edit it (See my old post [Modify DEFINER on Many Views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/modify-definer-on-many-views/4131#4131) or this other one [How do I change the DEFINER of a VIEW in Mysql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/how-do-i-change-the-definer-of-a-view-in-mysql?lq=1))

**WARNING**: If any one extended INSERT command has a syntax problem or improperly escaped or encapsulated data, the hundreds of rows in that one INSERT may not be loaded.

## SUGGESTION #2

Find out the original user who made the view, and recreate that user

Run this query : `select * from mysql.tables_priv;`

This will show all table-level and column-level grants. Look at the first three columns and figure out what GRANT command to make that user again.

Comment: `GRANT CREATE VIEW ON *.* TO 'backup'@'%';` didn't work ;)

Comment: Any disadvantage of using `-f`?

Comment: Added warning to use of `-f`

Comment: Use `-f` with extreme caution, because it masks errors, by definition, leaving you with an incomplete backup.  Last I checked, it incorrectly leaves the exit status of the dump process set to 0, even if errors occurred.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: Can I update the user of the VIEW?