# MySQL Views Authorization

Tags: mysql, view, authorization

Questions:

- Is there a way, using SQL, to identify how many views are in the database per user?
- How can you authorize/deny users access to delete views created by another user?

Comment: 1. You should check the database information_schema. 2. No, a user has DROP permissions or not. You can store permissions on a table-based level though.

Comment: 1. I want to list the view from information_schema on user basis. Is it possible to get it through query. Can you provide such query 2. Okay.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition of information_schema.views:

```
mysql> show create table information_schema.views\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: VIEWS
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `VIEWS` (
  `TABLE_CATALOG` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VIEW_DEFINITION` longtext NOT NULL,
  `CHECK_OPTION` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IS_UPDATABLE` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DEFINER` varchar(77) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SECURITY_TYPE` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COLLATION_CONNECTION` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here is how you can count the views per database per user

```
SELECT COUNT(1) ViewCount,table_schema,definer
FROM information_schema.views
GROUP BY table_schema,definer;
```

I am not that sure about access/denial of views. In the `information_schema.views` table, there is field called `SECURITY_TYPE` (which have values `DEFINER` and `INVOKER`).

If a View has `SECURITY_TYPE` as `INVOKER`, everybody and his grandmother can `SELECT` from that View. My guess is that you would have to set the `SECURITY_TYPE` to `DEFINER` to restrict everyone from running a `SELECT` from that View. Of course any user with `SUPER` privilege and the definer can a `SELECT` on that View.

Changing the `SECURITY_TYPE` is a little painful.

You can mysqldump all views. Here is a post I made back on July 26, 2011 : [Modify DEFINER on Many Views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/modify-definer-on-many-views/4131#4131). [@DTest had an even more concise answer using ALTER VIEW](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4130/877).

Edit the output file in vi or some other editor to change the `SECURITY TYPE` of any View you wish. Then, jus reimport the view from that text file.

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

1. SELECT 
   COUNT(*) 
   FROM
   `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` 
   WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'db_name' 
   AND `TABLE_TYPE` = 'VIEW' ;

This will return # of views in a database.

1. You should not give DROP permission to other users and have CREATE VIEW and DROP user permission to user which can DROP a view like this:
   CREATE USER 'view'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'view'; 
   GRANT CREATE VIEW, DROP ON `sakila`.* TO 'view'@'%' ;

Comment: 1. Mahesh, somehow i want to list the view on the basis of users, but when i use the command SELECT * FROM information_schema.`TABLES` WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW' AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'database_name'; then i can see that information schema does not contain the name of the definer (user) who actually created that view. Eventually i need to use the command "USE information_schema;" and then i can get the list of the views on the basis of user like "SELECT * FROM views WHERE DEFINER LIKE "delta@localhost";"  2. PLEASE EXPLAIN WHAT IS SAKILA.* IN YOUR EXAMPLE

Comment: oops sakila is a database name here used for example.

Comment: This is exact query you are looking for i guess,

SELECT 
  COUNT(*),
  `TABLE_NAME`,
  `DEFINER` 
FROM
  information_schema.views 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'database_name' 
GROUP BY `Definer` ;

Note: You do not have to use USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA; 
everytime instead you can use fully qualified queries.