# How to grant super privilege to the user?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a user and given privileges to the user1.

```
`grant all privileges on db1.* to user1@'%' with grant option;
```

Am using mysql workbench to import dumps to my database. While importing dumps to database db1,error occurs stating that

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 49: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

In that dumps all tables are imported successfully but the error occurs while importing routines to the database. Is there anything wrong with the privilege, I have given to the user1. Please advice.

Answer (score 51):

In a politically correct sense, what you just asked for is impossible. Why ?

The [**SUPER privilege**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) is a global privilege, not a database level privilege.

When you created the user with

```
grant all privileges on db1.* to user1@'%' with grant option;
```

you populated the table `mysql.user` with `user='user1'` and `host='%'`. All other columns (global  privileges) were defaulted to 'N'. One of those columns is `Super_priv`. Here is the table:

```
mysql> desc mysql.user;
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Host                   | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| User                   | char(16)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Password               | char(41)                          | NO   |     |         |       |
| Select_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Insert_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Update_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Delete_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Drop_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Reload_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Shutdown_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Process_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| File_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Grant_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| References_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Index_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_db_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Super_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv  | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Lock_tables_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Execute_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_slave_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_client_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_view_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_view_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_routine_priv     | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_user_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Event_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Trigger_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tablespace_priv | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| ssl_type               | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |         |       |
| ssl_cipher             | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_issuer            | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_subject           | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| max_questions          | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_updates            | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_connections        | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_user_connections   | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| plugin                 | char(64)                          | YES  |     |         |       |
| authentication_string  | text                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password_expired       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
43 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

`Super_priv` appears right after `Show_db_priv`.

The database level privileges got populated into `mysql.db`. Here is it:

```
mysql> desc mysql.db;
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Host                  | char(60)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Db                    | char(64)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| User                  | char(16)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Select_priv           | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Insert_priv           | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Update_priv           | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Delete_priv           | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_priv           | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Drop_priv             | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Grant_priv            | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| References_priv       | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Index_priv            | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_priv            | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Lock_tables_priv      | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_view_priv      | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_view_priv        | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_routine_priv   | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Execute_priv          | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Event_priv            | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Trigger_priv          | enum('N','Y') | NO   |     | N       |       |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Notice that `Super_priv` does not exist in `mysql.db`.

To visualize this in pure SQL terms, login as user1 and run `SHOW GRANTS;` The output will have two lines:

- `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO user1@'%' ...`
- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.* TO user1@'%' ...`

There is a hack you can try but I normally would not recommend it.

STEP 01) Login to mysql as `root@localhost` (should have all privs)

STEP 02) Run this query

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Super_Priv='Y' WHERE user='user1' AND host='%';
```

STEP 03) Run this query

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

That theoretically should work. Then, user1 may work (I make no guarantees).

## UPDATE 2014-12-19 15:24 EST

[**Metafaniel**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/53742/metafaniel) just asked

> Great explanation, thanks. However if you do not reccomend that way to solve the problem, then what other way is the best one to gran a user this Super_priv?? Thanks! –  Metafaniel

Since a user with only DB access cannot have [SUPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super), the only thing one can do is change the DEFINER manually in the dump. The basic idea would be to mysqldump the routines alone to a text file. Then, edit the definer to `user1@'%'`. Then, you should be able to reload.

- `Oct 02, 2011` : [Can mysqldump dump triggers and procedures?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6420/can-mysqldump-dump-triggers-and-procedures/6423#6423)
- `Jul 25, 2011` : [DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS not included in mysqldump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/drop-procedure-if-exists-not-included-in-mysqldump/4092#4092)
- `Jul 25, 2011` : [Dump only the Stored Procedures in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/dump-only-the-stored-procedures-in-mysql/4089#4089)

Same Thing for Views

- `Mar 23, 2012` : [MySQL Views Authorization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11381/mysql-views-authorization/15489#15489)
- `Jul 26, 2011` : [Modify DEFINER on Many Views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/modify-definer-on-many-views/4131#4131)

Comment: using mariadb and the update statement "ERROR 1348 (HY000): Column 'Super_priv' is not updatable'

Comment: once i give grant access i still see all default value ( same like *_priv columns)

Answer (score 30):

I had the exact same problem. What I did was:

```
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user1@localhost
```

And problem solved.

CAVEAT: [Is there any danger in granting SUPER privileges to a user?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124066/is-there-any-danger-in-granting-super-privileges-to-a-user)

Answer (score 4):

"Access denied" error during the import process might be due to the privileges mismatch for the DEFINERs between the database exported and the database going to be imported. I faced the same situation and below command works well for me to import the database successfully.

```
cat db1.sql | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' | mysql -u user1 -p db1
```