# SlaveThreadCount at 0 for non-root user, should be 2

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

In MySQL 5.5 running on Ubuntu 14 in a master-master-slave configuration

From one of the masters, when executing the query below as a user with (ALL PRIVILEGES) on the database but no other privileges elsewhere, this query returns 0

```
SELECT COUNT(1) SlaveThreadCount 
FROM information_schema.processlist 
WHERE user='system user'
```

When executing the same user as root, I.E. (ALL PRIVILEGES) on everything, I get back the real slave count.

Any particular reason I'm getting back 0 and not the real SlaveThreadCount which is 2 in this case?

Is this is privileges issue?

If I run the query without there WHERE in the non-root user, I only see my processes.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist
```

If I run it in a root user, then I see all processes.

So definitely a permissions issue, so looks like I need PROCESS, just answered my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all privileges on a specific database, you cannot have the [PROCESS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege. Why ? The [PROCESS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege is not a database-level privilege. It's a global privilege. How ?

About 2.5 years ago, I answered [How to grant super privilege to the user?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63404/how-to-grant-super-privilege-to-the-user/63434#63434) Someone wanted the [SUPER privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) but only had all privileges on a database. I explained by mentioning how global grants and database-level grants are stored. In short, there is a column called `Super_priv` in the table `mysql.user` (where global grants are stored). That column does not exist in `mysql.db` (where database-level grants are stored).

The same exact thing applies to the [PROCESS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege. There is a column called `Process_priv` in the table `mysql.user`. That column does not exist in `mysql.db`.

Comment: Hi Rolando, yes and actually I did add the Super privilege as you explained and that worked out great. Thanks for the Process_priv column as well.