# Unable to query for thread information in mysql using root

Tags: mysql, permissions, mariadb, process

I'm connected to a server's mySql database hosted on google cloud using the user 'root' with a password. 
I was under the impression that the root user had all privileges but when I try to get the thread information using `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, I get an error:

```
[Error Code: 1227, SQL State: 42000] Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation
```

Does it have something to do with me trying to access the database remotely?
What's the difference between `root@localhost` and `root@%`?

Comment: Essentially http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63404/how-to-grant-super-privilege-to-the-user but with `PROCESS` instead of `SUPER`

Answer (score 2):

This is something you quickly learn with GCP (CloudSQL), AWS (RDS), and all Cloud Providers of MySQL: Even `root` does not have all privileges.

You could run `SHOW GRANTS` when logged in as `root`. Regardless of the privileges it says it has, the Cloud Provider will restrict it.

You asked for a difference between `root@localhost` and `root@%`

- `root@localhost` will allow you to connect to mysqld from within the OS of the MySQL Instance. This requires access mysqld via the socket file. Using any
- `root@%` will allow you to connect to mysqld from any server via TCP
- Please read my post about how mysqld authenticates users ([MySQL error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897))

Sadly, regardless of which `root` user you use and what `SHOW GRANTS` says you have, the Cloud Provider will preempt any operation that uses `SUPER` and `PROCESS`. [I have written 7 posts in the past 4 years describing how Amazon does this with RDS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20SUPER%20RDS). So, it is not surprising Google does the same thing with CloudSQL.

After all, they don't want to expose the MySQL Container with fixed log file sizes, log file locations, datadir location, and the OS itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there no way for me to bypass this restriction that cloud providers put on their database server? How can I monitor the state of my server if they take away these privileges?

Comment: Your only recourse is to go with an unmanaged approach. Either go with Amazon EC2 or Google Computer Engine and do the MySQL installation yourself. Then, you can manage MySQL and its configs like you would on a bare metal machine.