# Meaning of various user account privileges in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Reference the attached screenshot:

[image]

1. I created a non-root user, and gave it all privileges to a database. It now has `All Privileges` of `Type` -- `global` and `database-specific`. What's the difference between these 2 "Types"?
2. Why three `root` `User names`? What's the purpose of having so many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phpMyAdmin` shows you the privileges of the users with regard to the underlying `MySQL` database instance to which you're connected. So, the answers don't come from `phpMyAdmin`, but from `MySQL`.

> 1. I created a non-root user, and gave it all privileges to a database. It now has "All" privileges of "Type" -- "global" and "database-specific". What's the difference between these 2 "Types"?

You can have one user have certain privileges for a given database (that's the [`database-specific`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges), while s/he has some others for *all* the databases (that's the [`global`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-global-privileges)). Someone with `global` privileges can, for instance, *create* new databases. That's something that person won't be able to do it s/he has only *database-specific* privileges.

> 2. Why three "root" "User names"? What's the purpose of having so many?

In MySQL you can give different privileges to users based not only on the username, but also based on the `IP address` or `DNS name` from which they connect. In principle, [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) represents your local machine (or, in actuality, the machine where `phpMyAdmin` is running), accessed either via IP protocol version 4 or version 6, `127.0.0.1` represents `localhost` through IPv4, and `::1` represents your local machine via IPv6  (actually, they represent the [`virtua loopback interface`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface), but don't bother with the subtle distinction). However, `localhost` could be changed on the [`hosts` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) of the machine to have a different meaning (don't do it or your machine might become inoperative!).

You have the three different settings (I think that by default) because the client connecting to your database might be using either an IPv4 address, an IPv6 address, or an address that maps to the `localhost` name. This is done so that, no matter which is the connection method, the root user can access MySQL and setup and change the database(s).

If you would like the user `root` to be able to connect from a remote computer (apart from changing some default configuration parameters), you would need to give him/her permissions to connect from a certain IP address (such as `123.123.123.123`). [Check the `account names` documentation from MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html) for how to specify IP addresses, DNS names, or wildcards.

Comment: In this case: was it unnecessary to give the new user database specific privileges when the user already had all global privileges?

Comment: I can't tell 100% for sure, but my guess is your right, if the user had global privileges, having *the same* privileges on a database-specific case is unnecessary. However, keep in mind that if you have *both* of them, and you *remove* the global ones, the specific would remain only if they were actually specified explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

[Your second question was well covered by joanolo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/182124/877).

I would like to address your first question only.

On `Apr 17, 2014`, I answered this question : [How to grant super privilege to the user?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63404/how-to-grant-super-privilege-to-the-user/63434#63434). In that post, I explained how the [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege was impossible to grant to a database-specific user. I clarified the difference between global privileges and database-specific privileges by comparing the table structure of `mysql.user` and `mysql.db`.

To show the difference between them in terms of grants side-by-side, please run this query:

```
SELECT
REPLACE(glb,'_priv','') global_privilege,
IFNULL(REPLACE(dbs,'_priv',''),'NOT ALLOWED') database_privilege
FROM (SELECT A.column_name glb,B.column_name dbs FROM
(SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user'
AND column_name LIKE '%priv') A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='db'
AND column_name LIKE '%priv') B
ON A.column_name=B.column_name) AA;
```

When you run this in MySQL 5.7.12, you get the following output:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
| global_privilege  | database_privilege |
+-------------------+--------------------+
| Select            | Select             |
| Insert            | Insert             |
| Update            | Update             |
| Delete            | Delete             |
| Create            | Create             |
| Drop              | Drop               |
| Grant             | Grant              |
| References        | References         |
| Index             | Index              |
| Alter             | Alter              |
| Create_tmp_table  | Create_tmp_table   |
| Lock_tables       | Lock_tables        |
| Create_view       | Create_view        |
| Show_view         | Show_view          |
| Create_routine    | Create_routine     |
| Alter_routine     | Alter_routine      |
| Execute           | Execute            |
| Event             | Event              |
| Trigger           | Trigger            |
| Reload            | NOT ALLOWED        |
| Shutdown          | NOT ALLOWED        |
| Process           | NOT ALLOWED        |
| File              | NOT ALLOWED        |
| Show_db           | NOT ALLOWED        |
| Super             | NOT ALLOWED        |
| Repl_slave        | NOT ALLOWED        |
| Repl_client       | NOT ALLOWED        |
| Create_user       | NOT ALLOWED        |
| Create_tablespace | NOT ALLOWED        |
+-------------------+--------------------+
29 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Given this display, it is impossible to grant [RELOAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload), [SHUTDOWN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_shutdown), [PROCESS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process), [FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file), [SHOW DATABASES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-databases), [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super), [REPLICATION SLAVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_replication-slave), [REPLICATION CLIENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_replication-client), [CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-user), and [CREATE TABLESPACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-tablespace) to a database-specific user.

For example, you don't want a database-specific user to

- Shutdown the Database
- See the processlist of other users
- Setup Replication on their own
- Kill DB Connections
- Create a New User
- Create Giant Tablespace Files
- Load an External File into the Database
- Create External Files in the OS using [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)
- and so forth

## SUPPLEMENTAL INFO

There are also table-specific grants in `mysql.tables_priv` and column-specific grants in `mysql.columns_priv`. These grants are stored in `ENUM` columns.

Just run `DESC mysql.tables_priv;` and `DESC mysql.columns_priv;` and see.